# Why Google play rejected my app they saying "for violating our dangerous products policy"

Tags: android, google-play, media-player, vitamio

I uploaded my app on google play store but after few hours i got an email saying:

> This app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for
>   users.
>
> Below is the list of vulnerabilities and the corresponding APK
>   versions that were detected in your recent submission. Please upgrade
>   your app(s) as soon as possible and increment the version number of
>   the upgraded APK.
>
> **Vulnerability 
>   OpenSSL**
>
> The vulnerabilities were fixed in OpenSSL versions beginning with
>   1.0.1h, 1.0.0m, and 0.9.8za. To confirm your OpenSSL version, you can do a grep via:
>
> $ unzip -p YourApp.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL"
>
> You can find more information and next steps in this Google Help
>   Center article.

My app is an on-line radio, that play different radio stations using Internet.
**And also I am using Vitamio media player rather than the android defualt player class.**

Please help me i spent a lot of time on this app.

Comment: The reason for rejection explained in Google's response - please make sure titles are refined appropriately. Anyway, it would be interesting and/or useful to see the *full context / string*, as returned from the supplied command (which you can, and probably should, run yourself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally the problem is solved. As i said, i am using vitamio mediaPlayer. Which was v4.2.1, **just upgraded to [v4.2.6](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle)**. And now its working.

If anyone have issue of this kind then first try to upgrade your plug-ins.

Comment: You have published it again?is it successful?

Answer (score 2):

In `/libs` there is the`libvinit.so` for each core architecture.

Using the precompiled *.so file that they have included contain an OpneSSL vulnerability. Its a known issue with the media package.

The only recourse is to compile the libvinit.so files from source or get them from someone else online. The original developer can included the source code patches on their github  for compling the .so files, you only need apply their patches applied to their base packages, get the current android openssl code and compile against it: https://github.com/android/platform_external_openssl

This is a known issue many are facing - see the [Vitamio google community](https://plus.google.com/communities/113608906994449577780) for further discussion.

If needing help once started, just ask another question and leave it in my comments.

Comment: $ unzip -p YourApp.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL"
returns "GmsCore_OpenSSL"
Any idea how to upgrade OpenSSL?

Comment: You must recompile the C code libs which make libvinit.so and have the openssl code in a linkable folder it is looking for, it should pick it up. I believe the original dev had some openssl patches for the make files in his github link above.

Comment: @childofthehorn did you get any success? I am also stucked with the vitamio openSLL issue

Answer (score 0):

As per the following:

> The vulnerabilities were fixed in OpenSSL versions beginning with
>   1.0.1h, 1.0.0m, and 0.9.8za. To confirm your OpenSSL version, you can do a grep via:
>
> $ unzip -p YourApp.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL"

You clearly need to increment the version of OpenSSL. It it is used in one of the libraries, then make sure you get the latest version (where they might have fixed it). Or get the source and update it yourself before using.

Comment: what should be the version of openssl now ?

Comment: like the mail says, it was fixed in `1.0.1h, 1.0.0m, and 0.9.8za`. use anything above that to avoid rejection. Check on their site for the latest version. I don't know for sure.

Comment: I am getting this 'strings' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You know where we need to specify openssl version in any library ?

Comment: @AndroidMechanic can you please help to resolve these issue

Comment: @pallavi which issue?

Comment: @AndroidMechanic , The question that was asked here